# mysqli count query not returning correct values

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have been working on a count query that counts how many students were registered with a '/' for present and a 'N' for an absence for each class.

When I run this query, I don't get the class names, it displays an overall total for present which should be 5 but it replicates this for the absent count which should be 0.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);


?>

<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR|MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

?>



<?php

//Connection for database


$sql = "SELECT 
    Form_Group,
    COUNT(IF(Presence = '/', 1, NULL)) 'Present',
    COUNT(IF(Presence = 'N', 1, NULL)) 'Absent' FROM attendance GROUP BY Form_Group ORDER BY Form_Group";
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Summary</h1>
<table border="1" align="center" style="line-height:25px;">
<tr>
<th>Form</th>
<th>Present</th>
<th>Absent</th>
</tr>
<?php
//Fetch Data form database
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);



?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row->Form_Group; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->Present; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->Absent; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php

mysqli_close($conn);

?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using `group by` to get the proper counts

Comment: `ORDER BY Form_Group` should probably be `GROUP BY Form_group ORDER BY Form_Group`

Comment: Also, some sensible indentation would make your code much easier to read.

Comment: You cant use COUNT with such expressions, it will not evaluate the actual "filter" (aka `like 'something'`) you have to use another aggregate function with conditions.

Comment: Thank you. I have 5 entries in the database, the query is now outputting only one class with the correct presence count but it is replicating the value to the absent count.  The other two count rows are not showing.

Comment: @jorge caampos

Thank you, I am now getting the correct totals, but not all rows are being output:

Comment: LIKE is redundant in this context. I think you want `=` and `<>`

Comment: Please see updated code, it only counts one class, the other two don;'t show.

Comment: Redundant LIKE has now been removed.

Comment: Not sure how to loop:    $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);